# How to read external file in python?

Tags: python

i need to be able to save and get usernames and passwords from an external file. this is what i have done so far however it constantly says that username or password is incorrect even when i enter it correctly. does anyone know how to fix this problem.

this is my current code

```py
import time
print("Welcome...")
welcome = input("Do you have an acount? y/n: ")
if welcome == "n":
    while True:
        username  = input("Enter a username:")
        password  = input("Enter a password:")
        password1 = input("Confirm password:")
        if password == password1:
            file = open("gcsetask.txt", "a")
            file.write(username + ":" + password)
            file.write('\n')
            file.close()
            welcome = "y"
            time.sleep(0.4)
            print("now lets login")
            break
        print("Passwords do NOT match!")

if welcome == "y":
    while True:
        login1 = input("Enter username:")
        login2 = input("Enter Password:")
        file = open("gcsetask.txt", "r")
        data = file.readlines()
        file.close()
        if data == (login1 + ":" + login2):
            print("Welcome")
            break
        print("Incorrect username or password.")
```

Comment: `readlines()` returns a list. A list cannot be equal to `login1+":"+login2`.

Answer (score 2):

Three methods to read a file

1. `read()` It returns the read bytes in form of a string.

   `fileObject.read()`

You can also define, how many bytes to read by

```
`fileObject.read([n]) //If n is not define, it will read the whole file`
```

2. `readline([n])` It reads the line and return in the form of string, It only read single line

   `fileObject.readline([n])`
3. `readlines()` It reads all the lines of the file and return each line a string element in a list

   `fileObject.readlines()`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

When you use `file.readlines()`, the function returns a `list` of all lines in the file. Thus, when you define `data` as:

```
data = file.readlines()
```

if you `print(data)`, you get something similar to:

```
['user:pass\n'] # note the the \n at the end
```

Then, in the following line:

```
if data == (login1+":"+login2):
```

you're trying to compare a string (`login1+":"+login2`) with a list, which is always `False` because they have different type.

Changing the condition to:

```
if login1+":"+login2 in data:
```

should fix this problem (but you'll have a different one, see below).

---

#### About the trailing `\n`:

`file.readlines()` splits the lines in a list, but does not remove the newline character. This will cause your test to still fail always, because you don't account for it in the test.

Possible solutions are:

1) include the `\n` in the string you search:

```
if '{}:{}\n'.format(login1,login2) in data:
```

2) read the whole file and use `splitlines` instead, which will remove the newline characters

```
data = file.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: This does work though if you leave the password blank then the user will be allowed access.

Comment: Except that each string in the list ends with a newline. So `'user:pass'` will not be in the list, `'user:pass\n'` will be in the list.

Comment: @khelwood good point, I'll add that to the question because it's a rather annoying part of `readlines` that is often forgotten

Comment: @GPhilo i am not the OP.

Comment: @CodeCupboard my bad, I scrolled up and saw your name in what I thought was the question (it was your answer instead)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code to look at each line of that file. Allowing multiple users.

```
import time
print("Welcome...")
welcome = input("Do you have an acount? y/n: ")
if welcome == "n":
    while True:
        username  = input("Enter a username:")
        password  = input("Enter a password:")
        password1 = input("Confirm password:")
        if password == password1:
            file = open("gcsetask.txt", "a")
            file.write(username+":"+password)
            file.write('\n')
            file.close()
            welcome = "y"
            time.sleep(0.4)
            print("now lets login")
            break
        print("Passwords do NOT match!")

if welcome == "y":
    while True:
        login1 = input("Enter username:")
        login2 = input("Enter Password:")
        file = open("gcsetask.txt", "r")

        data = file.readlines()
        file.close()
        for line in data:
            if line == (login1+":"+login2+"\n"):
                print("Welcome")
                break
        else:
            print("Incorrect username or password.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `readlines()` saves each line in a string inside a list.

If a file contains-
first line
second line

`readlines()` gives: ['first line','second line']

Try accessing them using index such as data[0] and data[1]

Answer (score 0):

The `readlines` method returns the list of lines which you need to iterate on it to find the appropriate login information.

```py
data = file.readlines()
login_info = f"{login1}:{login2}\n"
if login_info in data:
    print("Welcome")
    break
```

And also you can remove `\n` from the end of each line using `splitlines`.

```py
data = file.read().splitlines()
login_info = f"{login1}:{login2}"
if login_info in data:
    print("Welcome")
    break
```

And another alternative is remove `\n` from parsed lines manually.

```py
data = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file.readlines()]
login_info = f"{login1}:{login2}"
if login_info in data:
    print("Welcome")
    break
```

Comment: Side-note: you might want to specify that to use f-strings the OP needs python 3.7+